# ASP.NET Web Application: changing bootstrap css file results dissapearing nav bar buttoms

Tags: css, asp.net, twitter-bootstrap, visual-studio-2017

I make a new asp.net web application (MVC) in V.S.2017 and then download bootstrap.css from a bootstrap theme provider on web. I change the downloaded file name to "bootstrap-cosmo.css" and copy it to contents folder. then I replace this line of code in App_Start/BundleConfig.cs:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

with this on:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-cosmo.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

then press ctrl+F5 and My navigation bar almost disappear!

Where is the problem? notice that I follow step by step from a video course.

Answer (score 0):

You need to keep the original bootstrap css file and add the optional theme css file:

```
bundles.Add(new StyleBundle("~/Content/css").Include(
                  "~/Content/bootstrap.css",
                  "~/Content/bootstrap-cosmo.css",
                  "~/Content/site.css"));
```

The theme itself most likely does not contain the complete bootstrap.css content. It merely overwrides, the content it does want to theme / change.

Reference: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/getting-started/#download-cdn

Comment: Tnx, the navigation bar came back, but it looks disordered! the application name goes to top right (from top left). and nav bottoms listed verticaly! font size also became smaller!

Comment: @SeyedAmirMousavian I have the same problem. Did you end up fixing it?

Answer (score 0):

Make sure the template that you are downloading is the same version of bootstrap as the default one being used by the program. I had this problem occur when trying to use a template for 4.1.1, but the version of bootstrap that ASP.Net 2.0 chose to use was 3.3.7.

The default bootstrap css will have its version in the comments at the beginning of the file, likewise for the template.